# Add a new column to dataset and populate it from values in array using Java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a Dataset and I want to add a new column to that. I want to populate the new column with values from array/list, so that the first row in dataset has value in new column as first index of array/list, second row has value in new column as second index of array/list and so on.

This is the code I have been using

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("test")
                .master("local")
//                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();

        //preparing the dataset
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList("abc", "abc", "xyz");
        Dataset<String> dataDs = spark.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING());
        dataDs.show();

        //adding to new column
        List<String> columns=new ArrayList<String>();
        columns.add("1");
        columns.add("2");
        columns.add("3");
        dataDs.withColumn("spanish_hi", functions.array(columns.stream().map(functions::col).toArray(Column[]::new)))
                .show();
```

I have been trying to use a list also(as in above example) and also tried using functions.lit() but seems it's for constant values only. I am stuck with this since last evening, so would be thankful if anyone can help me in this.